# how to replace blank fields in a datettime pandas dataframe with None

Tags: python, pandas

The goal here is to convert all date strings to datetime format and anything that does not look like a datetime needs to be None

```py
import pandas
#dataframe
df = pandas.DataFrame({'Date':['2014-10-20 10:44:31', '2014-10-23 09:33:46', '2014-10-01 09:38:45', '', None, pandas.NaT]})
# convert to datetime
pandas.to_datetime(df['Date'],errors='coerce')
# make Nat to None
df['Date'] = df['Date'].where(pandas.notnull(df['Date']), None)
# get all columns that are object in the dataframe
object_columns = df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns
# strip white space and replace blank with None
df[object_columns] = df[object_columns].apply(lambda x: x.str.strip()).replace('',None)
#### weird behaviour for the row 4! it should be None!!
print(df)
```

Can anyone tell me why row4 is converted from '' to 2014-10-01 09:38:45!!? It should be None!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign it back

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],errors='coerce')
```

Then change to object

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype('object').where(pd.notnull(df['Date']), None)
df
Out[191]: 
                  Date
0  2014-10-20 10:44:31
1  2014-10-23 09:33:46
2  2014-10-01 09:38:45
3                 None
4                 None
5                 None
```

Comment: I noticed that after I posted the question. I ended up with Nat instead of None.. which when I am inserting to the database I am getting 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM instead of null

Comment: @syrkull convert to object